# How to prove that this block-matrix is positive-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, block-matrices

I have a $3n\times3n$ symmetric block matrix that I need to prove is positive definite:
$$
M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
 M_{1,1}&\dots&M_{1,n}\\
 \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
 M_{n,1}&\dots&M_{n,n}\\
 \end{array}\right).
$$
Given a set of points $\{ \mathbf{x}_i \}_{i=1}^n$ define $\mathbf{x}_{ij} = \mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{x}_{j}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ as the vector joining the $i$th and $j$th point then $$M_{ij} = (d_{ij}+\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}d_{ij}^3)I+(d_{ij}^3-\frac{3\epsilon^2}{2}d_{ij}^5)\mathbf{x}_{ij}\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T$$ is a $3\times3$ symmetric positive definite(*) matrix, $I$ the 3D identity matrix, $d_{ij} = (\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\mathbf{x}_{ij}+\epsilon^2)^{-1/2}$ is a positive definite scalar function and $0<\epsilon<<1$ is a small positive parameter.

I have a lot of numerical evidence(**) to believe that the this matrix is positive definite for any reasonable choice of $\epsilon$ and any distribution/number of points $\{ \mathbf{x}_i \}_{i=1}^n$; however, a general proof eludes me. Any ideas on how to **prove that this matrix is positive definite?**

If this is easy for you: what about the case where $\epsilon=\epsilon_j$ depends on $j$ but not $i$, such that $M_{ij}\ne M_{ji}$? (Although $M_{ij}^T=M_{ij}$ still)

If it turns out that this matrix is not positive definite in general, are there conditions on the distribution of points that guarantee that it will be positive definite?

Thank you in advanced!

(*) We know $M_{ij}$ is SPD as the eigenvalues, which can be easily calculated with MAPLE, are all positive and real.

(**) The eigenvalues, which are numerically calculated in MATLAB, asymptotically approach zero from above as $\epsilon$, $1/n$ and $||\mathbf{x}_{ij}||$ all approach zero.

Comment: Do we know anything about the size of $d_{ij}$? For instance, it can be shown that this matrix is positive definite for sufficiently large $\|\mathbf x_{ij}\|$, i.e. sufficiently small $d_{ij}$.

Comment: The fact that $\epsilon$ is small simplifies things in that it suffices to show that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}M$ is positive definite.

Comment: Actually, I'm not so sure about that first comment

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! For my particular problem,  we unfortunately can't say much about the norm except that it is bounded from above by one: $\|\mathbf{x}_{ij}\|\le 1$ so $d_{ij}$, is not so small unfortunately. If it helps, however, we can make an assumption that all the points are separated by at least some value: $a<\|\mathbf{x}_{ij}\|\le 1$ if that helps with the proof. Hopefully we can make $a$ as small as possible in this case!

Let me think about your answer for a bit and I'll get back to ya. I haven't thought of doing this before so could be a on to something!

Comment: All right. I just thought of something else: from the "thoughts on the problem" below, it follows that we can guarantee that $M$ will be positive definite (for sufficiently small $\epsilon$) whenever the matrix $D$ (with entries $d_{ij}$) is itself positive definite.

Comment: I think that this is definitely a step in the right direction. You can show that  is positive definite as it is the distance matrix of a radial basis function. Remember tho that $d_{ij}$ blows up to infinity as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ for $i=j$. However, as you said, positive definiteness of $D$ seems like the way towards a proof. I'll work on it over the next day or two!

Comment: With the observations that we have so far we can completely prove everything that you’re interested in

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts on the problem:

The matrix $A$ with blocks $A_{ij} = d_{ij} I$ can be written as $A = D \otimes I$, where $D$ has entries $d_{ij}$ and $\otimes$ is a Kronecker product. The matrix $B$ with blocks $B_{ij} = d_{ij}^3\mathbf x_{ij}\mathbf x_{ij}^T$ is given by 
$$
B = \sum_{i,j} d_{ij}^3 (\mathbf e_i\mathbf e_j)^T \otimes (\mathbf x_i - \mathbf x_j)(\mathbf x_i - \mathbf x_j)^T
\\
= \sum_{i,j} d_{ij}^3 [\mathbf e_i \otimes (\mathbf x_i - \mathbf x_j)][\mathbf e_j \otimes (\mathbf x_i - \mathbf x_j)]^T
\\ 
= [\mathbf e^T \otimes \mathbf X - \mathbf X \otimes \mathbf e^T]
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(D))
[\mathbf e^T \otimes \mathbf X - \mathbf X \otimes \mathbf e^T]^T,
$$
where $\mathbf X$ is the matrix with columns $\mathbf x_i$, $\mathbf e_i \in \Bbb R^n$ denotes the $i$th standard basis vector, $\mathbf e = (1,\dots,1)^T \in \Bbb R^n$, and vec denotes the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) operator.

The limit of $M$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ is $A + B$.